Drools Kie-Api import is not resolved
I am a very basic Java guy with very limited knowledge. Looking for help from Java pros. Thanks in advance!
Recently, I upgraded Eclipse IDE from Neon to Version 2023-12 (4.30.0) and Build ID 20231201-2043 and also updated Java from 1.8 to 23. I deleted all Eclipse folders (both hidden and regular) downloaded the latest version and installed like new Eclipse setup with Java 23.
Now all my Junit projects have "X" mark which was working fine earlier version.  The error is "The import org.kie cannot be resolved". Eclipse is suggesting a project fix (please see screenshot)
enter image description here
but the drools version used in the project is 7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003. The project should use 7.44 version of kie jars but not why it's suggesting 7.14 jar
The project is a clean copy from the repository with no changes to it. When I compared the Maven dependencies of the project with my teammates I noticed most of the dependencies were missing and also all dependencies were greyed out in my project. I am attaching the POM.xml of a project and screenshots of maven dependencies from my project as well as from my teammate.
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ihealth.icm</groupId>
    <artifactId>abcde-junit-professional</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

<!--    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.redhat.ba</groupId>
                <artifactId>ba-platform-bom</artifactId>
                <version>7.2.0.GA-redhat-00002</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement> -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.cxxxitx.soa</groupId>
            <artifactId>soa-common</artifactId>
            <version>9.90.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ixxxxxh.icm</groupId>
      <artifactId>rhdm</artifactId>
      <version>12.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cxxxxxi.di</groupId>
      <artifactId>di-utilities</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
            <version>7.44.0.Final-redhat-00003</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Maven Dependencies from my project
enter image description here
Maven Dependencies for the same project from my teammates
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Note: POM xml is same between 2 of us. The changes from environment to my teammates are

Java version JDK23 versus java 1.8
Eclipse IDE is different.

I spent at least a week on the Internet to a find solution to my problem but none of them were solving my problem.
Suggestions or Solutions tried from Stackoverflow & Internet

Change the scope from "Test" to "Compile" for grey out issue
Adding referring library for missing dependencies.
Installed JRE and Execution environment version to use JDK1.8
Adding Kie-api dependency to pom. It solves kie errors but pom xml throw error. Without dependency is working for other than it should work for me too
Clean, install ..maven update project .tried so many times
and many other options and solutions suggested on the internet.

None of them solved my core problem. Is it a Java version that messed my environment? Hope I get a solution from the experts. Thanks a lot in advance!
mvn -X package ...log also added:
[INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time:  3.903 s [INFO] Finished at: 2024-10-28T16:20:22-04:00 [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project aetna-junit-professional: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project aetna-junit-professional: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?

What error was thrown when you added the Kie-api dependency to your pom? And unless you are trying out JDK 23 features, stick to a LTS version like 21.

Drools 7.44 doesn't support JDK 23. That is a very old version, most probably the maximum supported version is JDK 11, but I would suggest staying with JDK 8

The Java used in your projects is independent from the Java used to run Eclipse. To run Eclipse, better use the Java that is shipped with Eclipse rather than a Java installed on your system. What do you mean "I deleted all Eclipse folders"? If you deleted your .settings folder than you erased all your project specific settings for no reasons. You said you updated Java from 1.8 to 23 but in your pom.xml you still have Java 1.8 (<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>). The dependencies shown in darker ("greyed out") are accessible only in test code, not in the main code.

@nitind - Thanks for responding to my question. I don't get any pom errors when kie-api added. But I am not sure why that should be case if everyone else doesn't have issue with org.drools version.  I'll lower the JDK and will give a try..

@YeserAmer - Thank you! I'll try with lower version of JDK.

@howlger - I updated the JDK to 23 but I am using a compiler version of 1.8 for these projects. Thank you for the response. I'll try lowering the JDK version as other suggested.

@YeserAmer - I hava another project where it uses reflections...I have to move to a greater version of JDK.

Still no solution to the problem.
